# Adding header files to eclipse build path for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use this: http://www.minixml.org/index.php

I'd like to get these includes to work on Eclipse for Windows.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Left-click your project and choose `Properties`, then go to the following section: `C/C++ General`, and then `Paths and Symbols`, then select `Includes` tab, in `Languages` list choose `GNU C++` (or whichever toolchain is your current). Now you can see `Add...` button to the very right, click it and provide a path to the directory which contains includes, for example: `D:\Libraries\MiniXML\include`. Don't forget to check the `Add to all configurations` checkbox. That's it, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexander-Shukaev [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15937340/1820106), adding Include **Path** (-I) is done using `Properties` → `C/C++ General` → `Paths and Symbols` → `Includes`.

OTH, adding Include **File** (-include, AKA 'forced include') is done using `Properties` → `C/C++ General` → `Paths and Symbols` → `Includes Files`.

Note #1: as of Eclipse Oxygen, there is another way to do that - `Properties` → `C/C++ General` → `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.` → `CDT User Settings Entries` → `Add` → `Include File` (use the drop-down box). Not clear way one would want either.

Note #2: use of variables helps to set configuration specific settings. For example - `${ProjDirPath}/${ConfigName}/config.h`