# Make Eclipse CDT pre-include a header file, to avoid error: "Symbol <symbol> could not be resolved"

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to make the Eclipse editor presume that a specific C header file has already been included, without having to #include it explicitly?

For example, how can we achieve:

```
#include "common_type_defs.h"
#include "special_type_defs.h" // Don't want to have to mention this header file

main()
{
  common_type var1;
  special_type var2;
  .....
}
```

by writing only:

```
#include "common_type_def.h"

main()
{
  common_type var1;
  special_type var2; // Eclipse editor: "Symbol 'special_type' could not be resolved"
  .....
}
```

without getting the Eclipse editor annotation error: "Symbol 'special_type' could not be resolved".

The reason is, the project uses a custom scripted build system. The special header files are added automatically by the build system, selected from different libraries. So the build succeeds.

I have added the special header folder to the include paths of the project. This allows me to hit [F3] and jump to the definition of "special_type". It is just that the editor flags an error.

I do not want to silence the error because I want to catch real errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, what did you end up doing?

Comment: The workaround is to use a different "build configurations" and set the different include files in the build configuration.

Comment: ... but where do you add include files through the build configuration?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45141415/1820106) how to do that using Eclipse's Project Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: 
**Project properties** → **C/C++ General** → **Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.** → **Entries** → **GNU C** 
Select **CDT User Setting Entries** and than click **Add** button. Select **Include File** and enter your preprocessor pre-include file here.

Apply and rebuild indexer.

[image: My pre-included ppdefs.h file]

> I am using Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Comment: “CDT User Setting Entries” settings will end up in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core folder inside the workspace instead of the .cproject file. Which will be a challenge for a version control.

Answer (score 1):

Do additional define in your build system and then:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMBUILDER
#include "special_type_defs.h" // Don't want to have to mention this header file
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, the build system is not written in C and the C source code must not be modified. The build system is a set of scripts which parse the C source code and add what is missing according to specific settings. So this solution could not work.

Therefore the options are:
(1) use another editor,
(2) silence the error,
(3) somehow convince Eclipse that this file *is* included.

As I love Eclipse, I want to find out how to do the latter one.

Comment: I don't quite understand this answer. Where does that code snippet go? Do you mean it stays in the source file?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating different "build configurations", for each build option of the build system. There I can add the background header files, as required.

One disadvantage is that I must maintain the different build configurations to mirror the build system: when new header files are added to the build system, the same files must also be added to the eclipse build configuration. So this solution will be unsuitable for big team projects where multiple people frequently change the included files because you could easily miss a file change or two. But it works well for small teams and infrequent changes.